# Writing horizontally and vertically at the same time

Tags: vertical-alignment, signatures

I am trying to make a latex document that contains what is on the picture but I am stuck. Can you help me, please?

[image]

This is what I could do so far.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}   %left column
\vrule
text text text
text text text
text text text
text text text
text text text
\begin{turn}{90}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Lab XXXX\\
Td............\\
\end{minipage}
\end{turn}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{6cm} %right column
\begin{center}
A text here
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

here is the result. [image]

But \vruler doesn't seem to give the needed result.

Comment: Try rotatebox. There should be enough instructions for it.

Comment: What are you stuck on, what does your current code and output look like?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `\rotatebox`, taking as origin the upper left corner.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
XXXXX XXXXX \\
Professor of XXX \\
\texttt{XXXXX@email.com}

\bigskip

\noindent
\rotatebox[origin=ul]{90}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  Laboratory of YYYY \\
  Tel: 00123456 \\
  Address: somewhere
  \end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. Can you help on how to draw that vertical line too please?

Comment: That depends on whether it should be inside or outside the text area.

Answer (score 2):

Does help you get started?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext, rotating}
\begin{document}

XXXXX XXXXXX\\
Professor of XXXXXX\\
XXXXX\@email.com\\

\begin{turn}{90}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Lab XXXX\\
Td............\\
\end{minipage}
\end{turn}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you *try* it?

Answer (score 2):

This shows how to add a line the the left.  I arbitrarily chose a line width of 0.4pt and a gop of 2pt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\noindent\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr\topskip-\textheight}[0pt][0pt]{\rule{0.4pt}{\textheight}}\hspace{2pt}}%
Outside the text area.

\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\noindent\raisebox{\dimexpr\topskip-\textheight}[0pt][0pt]{\rule{0.4pt}{\textheight}}%
\hspace{2pt}\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-0.4pt-2pt}
Inside the text area.

\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```